# is Mobilizer capable of emulating perfectly the behavior of scripts as well?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I recently took a look at Mobilizer http://www.springbox.com/mobilizer/

It's pretty amazing, being able to simulate the interfaces of iphones and stuff.

However, my question is that is it actually capable of rendering the exact same behavior not just for layout but for the javascript scripts?

I mean it will pretty hurt to find out that the script ran correctly in the emulator only to fail in the real scenario...

Answer (score 0):

This program will not emulate the actual phone OS. As far as I can tell, it is just loading up the page in an internal (desktop based) browser and displaying it within the phone with the correct dimensions etc. It is probably sending the [User Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string that belongs to that device as well.

So, It is useful for testing your layout on different screen sizes, testing your mobile redirect scripts and saving out mockups of the website on a device for clients.

It is **definitely** not to be used to test if your website will work on that device.

To accurately test without a physical device on:

- iOS, check out the [iOS simulator that comes with X Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/125-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html).
- Android, check out the [Android emulator that comes with the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).
- WebOS, check out the [WebOS emulator from the webOS SDK](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/dev-guide/tools/emulator.html)
- Blackberry, check out the [Blackberry Simulators](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/downloads/simulators/) (Windows only)

Unfortunately, there is no app that makes testing on all these devices easy as it seemed 'Mobilizer' did. If you can, it's always good to test on the actual devices too as emulators aren't always perfect.